# How do I make an Android CheckBoxPreference unclickable?

Tags: java, android, checkboxpreference

Here's my code:

```
<PreferenceCategory
   android:summary="Fade information"
   android:title="Fade Effects"> 

   <CheckBoxPreference
     android:title="Fade In/Out"
            android:defaultValue="false"         
            android:key="fadeIn"/> 

   <CheckBoxPreference
     android:title="Heartbeat"
            android:defaultValue="false"   
            android:key="heartbeat" />  

   <CheckBoxPreference
     android:title="Pulse"
            android:defaultValue="false"               
            android:key="pulse" />  

   <CheckBoxPreference
     android:title="None"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="none" />  
</PreferenceCategory>
```

I'm basically trying to figure out how to make those CheckBoxes appear as they are, but having them unclickable by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:enabled="false"` from your XML, or `setEnabled()` in Java code.

Answer (score 7):

Using `android:enabled="false"` is incorrect as this actually completely disables a `View` (it also greys it out which is the main issue). What you want to do instead is:

`android:clickable="false"`

This simply stops the user clicking the `View` but doesn't officially 'disable' it. I think that's more what you are looking for.

Comment: Clickable as false didn't have any effect on the Preference.

Comment: There is no `android:clickable` attribute [on `CheckBoxPreference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html), which is what this question is about.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `android:selectable="false"` in xml if you don't wish to gray out the CheckboxPreference.